# como resolver "object library not registered" VB6

Tags: visual-basic-6

De repente, não consigo mais usar meus programas por causa dessa mensagem:

> Object library not registered

Não consigo resolver.

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Adicione mais detalhes sobre seu problema, apenas com essas informações fica difícil alguém lhe ajudar. Quanto mais informações sua pergunta conter, melhor.